# php server background processes

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I would like to know how to achieve some php server background functionality to process some evaluations every second (independent on users viewing page).

My current solution is done with cron job that runs every second. I would like to know if there is any other options or possibilities.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The cronjob is correct.

Comment: Though every second seems excessive, every minute is a bit more practical - didn't realise cron would actually run to every second

Comment: It must be evaluated every second because it needs to execute planned actions on scheduled time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cron, I recommend you to write a daemon, you can do this in PHP, python, node.js or the language that you prefer. Once you have your script written, you can convert it in a daemon using [upstar](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

1) Write your program with a while loop and sleep.

```
while (1)
{
  if (x == y) {
    echo "yay!"
  }
  sleep(1);
}
```

2) Write the program with a wrapper, so it never crashes.

```
while test 1
do
php /usr/local/bin/continual_process.php
done
```

The problem with this approach is that it CONSTANTLY uses CPU cycles for it.  If you write your program as a node.js application, the event-driven architecture and `setTimeout` feature can help scale your application (and get you thinking about a different mindset for solving issues).

Additionally, you have to consider how long it takes to process the loop.  If you call the program every second, but it takes 2 seconds to loop, you are eating up your processes!  The `sleep` method may not worth either.  If the loop takes 2 seconds, and you `sleep 1`, you are running the process every 3 seconds.

Finally, if your process is quick and light (under 1 second loop), considering using `setInterval`.

Comment: setTimeout in a javascript engine is unlikely to use less CPU cycles than sleep(1) in c or php.

Comment: The semantics of setTimeout are roughly the same as in a web browser: the timeout arg is a minimum number of ms to wait before executing, not a guarantee. The command is only checked and thus **non-blocking** on each polling cycle (in node) VS it being **BLOCKING** in C and PHP.

Comment: Of course, this is exactly the point. Blocking does not mean it blocks the CPU, it means the process tells the kernel: I'm not doing anything for x amount of time, give me CPU time again after that. Since NodeJS can actually do stuff in the background while you're 'sleeping', CPU consumption may well be non-0, compared to C / PHP where CPU usage definitely is 0.

Comment: I can imagine the V8 engine could optimize this if there's only 1 pending event, and it's a timeout.. But even then the CPU consumption would be equal (0).

Comment: If you're curious, write a small script with `sleep(100)` and check top/htop and read the process state & cpu usage. Should be idle or sleeping depending on your OS. It's not a crazy while loop that checks the current time after every iteration ;)